# Deleting files inside docker container not freeing up space on host system

Tags: docker, containers, linux-containers

My docker containers have some data generated from applications running in the container. 
Even when I delete those files inside container system I can still see them existing on host system at 
var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/c76a6e7874bbfb7d18c7f8aeaed154460ca5b8a18e1823d813b621bc7c42afa8/rootfs/var/www/html/etc/app/files

This is not freeing up space on host system. Any thoughts on this ?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Docker's file system works in manner similar to GIT. When you make a commit a snapshot of the file system is preserved so that it can reproduced. What this means is that committed files cannot be truly deleted (unless the docker image is completely purged)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that docker and the device mapper reserved 10 Gb (by default, you can modify this, see http://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/01/29/docker-device-mapper-resize/) so you can have many files or 0 file in your container, you will use the same size.

Comment: Okay but still if I am deleting something inside a container doesn't it delete & freeup the space on host system ?

Comment: It is similar to a KVM image of 10 Gb, http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/HOWTO1 if you are "Creating a disk image for the guest " so use this space. Wether you install many things in this space or not is not relevant, this space is used.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete it with image id.If you delete it with container name alone the space remains exists.
docker rmi